# How does iTether work (html5 iphone api)

Tags: iphone, ios, html

How does something like itether work?  Is there an HTML5 api that gives you this level of access to the device?  I would assume giving a web based app this much access is a huge security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Tethering's HTML5 app works by by using the iPhone as a proxy server, 
so one sets up an ad-hoc Wi-Fi network and runs special desktop software 
to direct HTTP traffic to the iPhone.

The HTML5 page loaded onto the iPhone pushes the traffic on and 
returns the result, creating tethering without having to get approval 
from Apple, or the network operator. ( [Original Source](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/03/12/tethering_iphone/) )

I think they are using HTML [WebSockets](http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html) detects the presence of a proxy server and automatically sets up a tunnel to pass through the proxy.